# Address of stack memory associated with local variable

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ function, trying to return an array of `float`:

```
float* get_my_weights(int e, int n, float a, float b) {
    float weights[10] = {1};
    weights[0] = e + n + a + b;
    return weights;
};
```

During the compilation, I got the following errors:

```
myFunction:4:12: error: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'weights' returned[-Werror,-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return weights;
           ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: `weights` doesn't exist after you return from `get_my_weights`. Your pointer to is is no longer usable.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks! How do I fix this then?

Comment: If you want to return an array by value, use `std::array<float, 10>` instead of a `float[10]`. Those can be copied around. Though a `std::vector<int>` of size 10 may be more desirable since it offers move semantics.

Comment: Beware that the answers in the duplicate are not very good...

Comment: Side note: `float weights[10] = {1};` only sets the first element to 1. The remainder are all set to zero. This doesn't affect this program in any way, but it comes as a nasty surprise to many who expect it to produce an array of 1s.